# Finding the location last occurrence of a character in a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of URLs:

site.com/about-us

site.com/blog/a-nice-post

site.com/privacy

site.com/blog/another-post

and I want to extract the text after the last / (i.e. the name of the specific page/post). The result will be:

about-us

a-nice-post

privacy

another-post

1. How can I make the extraction to get the desired list?

I figured that if I could get the location of the last "/" I can use the MID function to do so.

2. What if the links have "/" as a final character? e.g. site.com/blog/a-nice-post/

How can I still extract the page name (a-nice-post)?

Comment: I found a way to do it. It's cumbersome but is working. Let's say the string is in cell A2.

1. In cell C2: COUNTA(SPLIT(A2,"/")

2. In cell E2: COUNTA(SPLIT(A2,"/")

3. In cell B2: OFFSET(C2,0,C2)

So I basically split after each forward slash, count the number of segments and retrieve the last one. 
It's working but would love to see a cleaner solution. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
=regexextract(A1,"/([^/]+)/*$")
```

ie a slash, then a number of characters other than a slash, zero or more slashes and end of line.

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I admit I don't understand what part of the regular expression denotes that it will bring the last segment, but it works fine.

Comment: Glad it works for you. Basically it gets the last segment because it's anchored to the end of the line.